# Get a style switcher like on themeforest

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I would like to add a style switcher to my site and I like the ones used on themeforest templates.. How is that done and what library are they using?

Example: http://centum.envato.tabvn.com/demo.php

Slides in from the left side.

[image]

I use drupal so I'm hoping there is a module but I couldn't find anything like it.

Any ideas?

---

WHY AM I GETTINGS VOTED DOWN? PLEASE EXPLAIN IF I'VE DONE SOMETHING WRONG HERE

Answer (score 1):

This is fairly easy to create yourself just by adding classes with an onClick handler, and then styling with the classes how you see fit. They're probably not using a plugin for this but is actually a bespoke function they've created them selves with the jQuery library.

For example.

```
$('.style').on('click',function(){
   $('.itemToChange').addClass('styleOne');
});
```

Please see a basic example with this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c7gtV/).

Please note this is a **VERY** basic version, and the example you show is much more indepth

Answer (score 0):

if someone still looking here are two solutions

[Blast.js](http://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Minimal-jQuery-Based-Site-Theme-Color-Scheme-Switcher-Blast-js.html) or 
[JTS](http://www.jqueryscript.net/other/jQuery-Plugin-To-Create-A-Theme-Skin-Switcher.html)

Answer (score -1):

The example you provided is using this

http://drupal.org/project/flexslider

EDIT

I'm sorry I got confused.

The style switcher is custom made by Envato, the company behind themeforest you can find the code here

http://centum.envato.tabvn.com/sites/all/themes/centum/js/switcher.js

Comment: Hi @Ateszki - I'm refering to the style switcher not the slider. Sorry for the confussion.